# Can't get REST response from Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, raspberry-pi

Hey guys this is my first question.

I'm trying to get rest response from a spring application put on Tomcat on my Raspberry Pi.

I configured a port forwarding to reach my raspberry from outside and I can also reach my Tomcat from outside. I put my Rest-App in the webapps-folder and it also works fine calling the index-file.

Now I tried to get my rest call but it tells me `Error 404`.

On my local machine Eclipse with Tomcat it works fine.

I tried to keep rest-call simple in just returning a String.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<Cocktail> getCocktail() {
    List<Cocktail> cocktails = DBHandler.getAllCocktails();

  return cocktails;
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getTest() {

  return "Test for Cocktail";
 }
```

I want to call like `myadress:8080/AppName/rest/cocktail/test` and get my String back.

Later I want to get data from a database but that's another story to tell.

Thanks for every suggestion and answer.

Comment: Additional things didn't know how to format right: Class hast Annotation @RestController
@RequestMapping("/cocktail") 
and i have another class extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and making the call start with /rest/*

Comment: Did you check the Tomcat logs on the Raspberry PI. To which path is the application bound? This might be different from your local environment.

Comment: Could you give me some more information? Which file shows the binding between the rest call? catalina.out tells me that the .war file is deployed correctly and i'm able to access the index-file of the spring app under the deployed .war name.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. it was right sitting in front of the computer.
I didn't gernerate sources with maven so my .war file was just with the index file and without resoources.
It's working fine now.